# DuckDuckGo not responding while OpenDNS is set

Tags: opendns, duckduckgo

I was using OpenDNS (Primary 208.67.222.222 and secondary 208.67.220.220) on my Mac. And it is not loading DuckDuckGo site on browser.

But when I unset the DNS, DuckDuckGo is accessible now. And I don't understand why?

[image: DNS Setup on Mac]

Comment: the servers in your post are returning duckduckgo.com's IP address for me. 'nslookup duckduckgo.com 208.67.222.222' gives me a valid address.

Answer (score 0):

Test using another DNS resolver, such as [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/) or [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

If one of those allow access that search engine, then **ask *OpenDNS* why they are blocking *DuckDuckGo***.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is that the DuckDuckGo site has banned the IP address
that you get from OpenDNS, because of some abuse done from this
address by a previous owner of it.

You need to use another VPN, or no VPN, if you wish to avoid this block.

Such a situation usually clears up after some time by itself, when
the DuckDuckGo site will remove this ban.

Comment: Some information : Most websites today implement defenses against some forms of attack, such as brute-force password attacks, denial of service and others. The only defense they have is to ban the attacking IP and block it, usually at the router level. When gaining a public IP from any kind of VPN service, there's a small chance of happening upon an IP that was used to attack websites. In that case, the solution is to try to chance the IP address, or wait, because such bans are not forever.